# What're the differences between receiving a SIGKILL signal and calling std::exit()?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Under Linux OS, what would the progress do when receiving a SIGKILL signal?
What're the differences between receiving a `SIGKILL` signal and calling `std::exit()`?

As per this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/485657/416809), which says that[emphasise mine]:

> Once any in-process kernel routines are resolved, the process state is changed from "dying" to "dead" and the kernel begins cleaning it up, ***similar to when a program exits normally***. Once the clean-up is complete, a greater-than-128 result code will be assigned (to indicate that the process was killed by a signal; see this answer for the messy details), and the process will transition into "zombie" state.

As per the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) which says that:

> The destructors of objects with thread local storage duration that are associated with the current thread, the destructors of objects with static storage duration, and the functions registered with std::atexit are executed concurrently

Comment: SIGKILL will kill your application without calling anything inside your program, not any destruction nor exit handlers. The process will simply removed from the core and the resources are freed ( mostly ).

Comment: @Klaus Why you say ***mostly***? What resources would not be freed?

Comment: you may have pending data in sockets or unreleased IPC communication. Maybe semaphores stay in blocked state.

Comment: what is not clear about the quotes? The first quote is talking about the OS doing clean up. The second quote talks about the clean up in your program, which is not done in the first case, and the OS clean up happens after that. Maybe thats the difference you missed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want to know whether the process would do some clean up or not before it actually dies when receiving the SIGKILL signal.

Comment: "the process state is changed from "dying" to "dead" and the kernel begins cleaning it up"  The process itself is not doing anything

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I see. Thank you so much. *"similar to when a program exits normally..."* confuses me. I think it means that the process itself may do some cleanup (like sth. `std::exit` does). You save me hours.

Comment: "similar to when a program exits normally..." just means that everything after " and the kernel begins ..." is just what happens anyhow when your process terminated, also when you call `exit` the OS will clean up after your process

Comment: With your generous help, I finally fully understand it. Thank you.